# Typing fully qualified type names in powershell?

Tags: powershell, namespaces

I want to reduce typing `System` and other root namespaces, for example

```
[string] $ComputerName = [Environment]::MachineName
```

vs.

```
[System.String] $ComputerName = [System.Environment]::MachineName
```

Another example:

```
[Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("192.168.1.1")
```

vs.

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("192.168.1.1")
```

Are there any reasons and specific situation when typing `System` and similar parent namespaces is required?

I often wonder why is there `System` namespace after all since everything is inside that namespace so what the deal with that namespace? it's a nonsense; what is the term `System` supposed to mean anyway? it's not related to operating system here. but to everything in NET framework.

I assume that there may be exceptions when calling static methods, but I don't know C# so unable to answer this myself.

Comment: Along what 'Mathias R. Jessen' is saying, without using the full namespace, you lose the IntelliSense when dot referencing stuff off the [System] root, thus forcing you to have already memorized the child of that [System.] beforehand. Who has a photographic/eidetic memory of all of those? So, even with leveraging the 'using namespace System.Net', pointed to, sure, you don't have to type [System], but you still to know what you want to use, which means using [System.] to find it, then use the shorthand after. So, no real escaping its use 100%.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In somewhat jumbled order:

> it's a nonsense; what is the term `System` supposed to mean anyway?

The "System" in question is the .NET runtime and framework. The original idea, as far as I understand, was that code that doesn't ship *with* .NET would fall under different namespaces - but multiple Microsoft-authored components built on top of .NET has since made use of `System` parent namespace - including all the APIs that make up PowerShell itself.

> I often wonder why is there [a] `System` namespace after all since everything is inside that namespace so what the deal with that namespace?

Not "everything" is inside the `System` namespace, but as mentioned above, everything that ships with the runtime or base class libary is - which is exactly why PowerShell automatically resolve type literals even if you omit `System.` from a qualified type name - PowerShell *is trying to help you reduce typing already*

> Are there any reasons and specific situation when typing System and similar parent namespaces is required?

Yes - when the parent namespace is *not* `System`.

The first example that comes to mind is the .NET wrapper classes for the Win32 registry API on Windows:

```
$HKLM = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView]::Default)
```

---

Now, for the actual question:

> I want to reduce typing `System` and other root namespaces

You can't add custom namespace prefixes (like `System`) to PowerShell's name resolution method, but you *can* declare automatic resolution of type names in *specific namespaces* in PowerShell 5 and up, with the [`using namespace` directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using).

### Without `using namespace`:

```
[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry("192.168.1.1")
```

### With `using namespace`:

```
using namespace System.Net

[Dns]::GetHostEntry("192.168.1.1")
```

When used in a script, any `using` directives must precede anything else in the file, including the `param` block.

`using namespace` directives will work in an interactive session as well, granted that you issue it as a separate statement:

```
PS> using namespace System.Net 
PS> [Dns] # still works!
```

Comment: I see, so the `System` is actually the same as `std` in C++. therefore avoiding System is almost always safe in powershell?

Comment: @metablaster kinda, except it's not quite comparable - omitting `System` only works in PowerShell because it deliberately (and silently) adds it for you when you omit it from a type name, the namespace of which doesn't already resolve

Answer (score 1):

By the way, powershell has a lot of "type accelerators" like [datetime], can you make your own, like [dt]:  [Boolean and bool difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60333603/boolean-and-bool-difference/60352476#60352476)

Comment: thank you, this is link from my own question, but I posted a new one since this is specific to NET namespaces. PowerShell is awesome and I'm obviously learning the basics :)